# Bitly url still converting to t.co

Tags: twitter

I just got a question about bitly url link. I recently use bitly api to covert all my long url to shorten for the purpose of Google Analytic tracking. However when I start sharing bitly url e.g. (bit.ly/liRJca) on twitter, it is still pointing to t.co/xxxx. I know that twitter only allow us to use 140 character to share.

Here is the sharing code I am using for twitter.

`$twit = "http://twitter.com/share?url=" . $lists['shortenurl'] . "&text=I like this work! Check it out. Voting starts on 23 May 2011 - amazing Canon Legria prizes to be won!";`

Comment: I figured out the answer ^^. I used this code for sharing instead of twitter.com/share?url=xxx<br /> <br />

$twit = "**http://twitter.com/home?status=**" . $tweeturl;</code>

It points to the correct bitly link...

Comment: that is only a temporary work around. At some point Twitter is going to wrap all links in tco.

Comment: tco -> bitly -> your site - this way you can still see the metrics of your share from bitly

Answer (score 5):

The bitly link isn't getting converted to tco. Tco is wrapping the bitly link. Users will hit the tco domain, get redirected to the bitly domain, and then to the long domain.